# Finding the max value in Power BI Column

Tags: ms-access, powerbi

I am sorry for bothering you with my issues and I am totally aware that this is probably pretty easy to solve. I also already searched the Internet but I am not able to apply the things I found.
I am totally new to PowerBi but need to fix this issue real quick.

So when I go to "Edit Queries" I have different tables on the left.
In one of them I've got one column for date, one for time and one for power output.
Now I want to find the highest value in "power output" and show this value and the date and time on the dashboard. What is the best way to do this? Add a new column? Add a new measure? And how do I do this? Which code do I need to use?

I really trying to learn by myself but I have literally no idea.
Please consider that I probably won't understand any technical terms..

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this...

- In Power BI Desktop, Open the Report View
- Create a new Measure (I called mine MaxValue, Numeric field = Cost)
- Enter the formula :

  **MaxValue = MAX('Table'[Cost])**
- Add a Card to your Report,
- While selecting the Card, drag that Measure : MaxValue to the Fields location on the right.
- Edit Queries can also be used by manipulating values in columns, aggregations, etc; but not required here.

See pictures:

[image: DAX formula for MaxValue]

[image: Max Value on a Card]

Comment: How did you add the screenshots to your answer?

Comment: When you add or edit a message, you get an icon that looks like a picture, use it to add images to your text. There is also a button at the bottom that reads [add picture]... More info at : https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help